# HIVE output specific string

Tags: string, hiveql

Is it possible to output specific string in HIVE, similar to echo in Bash?
I already know that I can do:

```
SELECT 1+1;
```

And it will output 2.

But sometimes I would need output as specific text directly from HIVE. It is not about to do workaround Bash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can execute shell commands from Hive, just start them with '! ':

```
hive>! echo test;
test
```